# Setting a minimum length for textarea

Tags: textarea, minimum

I am trying to make it so that this comment form on my wordpress website can not be submitted if the user does not enter enough data into the textarea.

I wrote this for the header

```
<script>
function CheckLength()
{
var msg_area = document.getElementById("Message");
msg_area.innerHTML = "";
if (document.getElementById("commentarea").value.length < 100) {
msg_area.innerHTML = "YOU DID NOT ENTER ENOUGH INFO FOR YOUR REVIEW";
}
else document.getElementById("commentform").submit();
}
</script>
```

And my form looks like this

```
<form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" name="commentform" id="commentform">


           <p><input size="36" type="text" name="author" /> Name <span class="required">*</span></p>
            <p><input size="36" type="text" name="email" /> Email <span class="required">*</span> (Not Published)</p>
            <p><input size="36" type="text" name="url" /> Website</p>
            <p><input size="36" type="text" name="server_ip" id="server_ip" /> Server IP/Hostname</p>
            <p><?php show_subscription_checkbox(); ?></p>     

            <p><textarea name="comment" id="commentarea" cols="100%" rows="20"></textarea></p>

        <p align="right"><input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Review" tabindex="5" onClick="CheckLength()"></p>
        <span id="Message" style="color:#ff0000"></span>


    <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />

    <?php /* do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); */ ?>
        </form>
```

The form spits out the error "YOU DID NOT ENTER ENOUGH INFO FOR YOUR REVIEW" if I type in less then 100 chars, but if I type more then a 100 chars the form does not submit. If I change the input type to submit it does submit, but it doesn't matter if < 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of your input button.

The error I get using your markup is that submit is not a function, because it thinks I'm referring to the submit button. The following should work:

```
<input type="button" name="submitbtn" id="submitbtn" value="Submit Review" tabindex="5" onClick="CheckLength()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you do this?

Put the check in the "onsubmit" event for the form:

```
<form action="wp-comments-post.php" onsubmit="return CheckLength();" method="post" name="commentform" id="commentform">
```

You'll have to update you function to return a Boolean:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function CheckLength()
{
    var msg_area = document.getElementById("Message");
    msg_area.innerHTML = "";
    if (document.getElementById("commentarea").value.length < 100) {
        msg_area.innerHTML = "YOU DID NOT ENTER ENOUGH INFO FOR YOUR REVIEW";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Then remove the onclick event from your submit button.

Comment: What will be the output of adding the check to the form instead of the submit?

Comment: I think what you have done is bad practice. By calling `document.getElementById("commentform").submit();` in your JS, you bypass the onclick event of your submit button. If you wanted to submit your form programmatically, my solution would allow you to  use that line of JS while still catching your minimum length requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
<script>
function CheckLength()
{
    var msg_area = document.getElementById("Message");
    msg_area.innerHTML = "";
    if (document.getElementById("commentarea").value.length < 100)
    {
        msg_area.innerHTML = "YOU DID NOT ENTER ENOUGH INFO FOR YOUR REVIEW";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("commentform").submit();
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```